# Active collision bounds in the BGE?

Tags: game-engine

How can I have collision bounds that are exact, even during animations. If I have a character with a simple rectangular prism, it won't be realistic. I could have an exact copy in shape but the animations will play and it will be ruined. I could have animations on the collision bounds, but then being stable to the ground won't happen. I could just have simple bounds then another set of perfect bounds, but dynamic object will hit only the simple one. There is obviously another technique for the next step in this topic. How can I have collision bounds that work with dynamic objects, and are perfect in shape to the original character that are also stable to the ground?

I would prefer solutions that do not include python.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I ignored the "no Python" requirement because the **absolute simplest** way of doing this requires very few lines of code.  Doing it brick-only would be loads of work and very dirty.

Attach this to your animated mesh and run it every frame.  It will update the physics to match the mesh.

```
import bge

def update(cont):
    own = cont.owner
    own.reinstancePhysicsMesh()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    update(bge.logic.getCurrentController())
```

[Example blend](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19279604/static/misc/physics_shape.zip)

Of course, being parented to the armature means it wont be affected by gravity.  So you'll need the armature parented to another object for controlling movement.  Make use of Collision Group / Collision Mask to prevent unwanted interference.

EDIT - [Example with collision masks](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19279604/static/misc/physics_shape_with_mask.zip)

Comment: Tell me this, when an object collides, i've seen, it hits what the object looks like. When will it register its collision?

Comment: The collision registers right when it hits.  You can add a Collision sensor -> And controller -> End Object to the falling object and confirm this.  Er, and it looks like a rogue property (dyn) found its way into the file.  It does nothing and I have deleted it.

Comment: Honestly, you did well. I had 2 of 3 of my biggest bge problems solved today. Let me implement it into my game files, and if it works i'll have you as correct answer. Otherwise, i'll update you on it, I will try to have it done soon.

Comment: How do I add the green/red borders?

Comment: That would be the physics visualization debug mode.  Toggle with Game -> Show Physics Visualization near the top of the window.

Comment: And one more thing, the bullet would collide with the parent of the armature, and you said to "Make use of Collision Group / Collision Mask to prevent unwanted interference." How would I use that to make the bullet not interfere with the controller?

Comment: Each object needs to be part of one or more collision groups.  Then you'll check a collision mask box for each group that the object should collide with.  It will take some thinking to narrow down which objects should belong to what group.  Basically the movement mesh should be in a group that isn't detected by the bullets.  Set in the physics panel.

Comment: Thanks. I have done instructions, and I placed a sphere with an animation where it just moves forward through the player. The white lines, the ones that stay the same all the time, seem to be the ones the ball hits. When the player is in his animation, the collision bounds don't seem to change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19663/discussion-between-pqftgs-and-blenderdev).

Comment: pq can you talk in chat pls?

Comment: This example should have everything you need.  The animated mesh updates the physics shape every frame, and the bullet (sphere) ignores the player parent object (cube).  If you are unable to replicate this in your own file, there is likely another object getting in the way.  If it works I'll update the answer.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19279604/static/misc/physics_shape_with_mask.zip

Comment: I replicated it to the exact, and my controller along with character keep colliding! I tried everything, and i'm starting to get really frustrated!

Comment: I can replicate it with 3 cubes, but not my situation! I have bounds, a character, and a rig. The rig is set to *no collision,* my character to *static,* and my controller to *dynamic.* Character is child of rig, and rig is child of controller. To be more specific, I want the character to not collide with bounds, but collide with bullets. I want bounds to not collide with character or bullets, but collide with map. I tried everything, and nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is *Rigid Body Collisions Shape*. This option lets you select how the collision bounds of the object collide with other objects. this can be found under the *Physics* tab.

[image]

Obviously, you don't want a man with cube collisions. *Triangle Mesh is the BEST option!*

This makes the collision surface a triangulated copy of your object and will move with your object even in animations.

Of course there are other options that the computer can calculate faster, so don't use *Triangle mesh* unless you need it. If *Box* will do, use it.

Here's an [example](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33480).

Comment: You can see what's happening in the *physics visualization* under game options.

Comment: I have already posted that answer, and the OP said it didn't work.

Comment: @BlenderDev what doesn't work about this answer?

Comment: With triangle mesh, it doesn't update with animations.

Comment: The exact issue with any standard RigidBody collisions.

Comment: May you post the .blend?

Comment: I actually don't want anyone to see it, it may seem weird to hear, but it is a long story. For the most part,  I have a character, a rig, and a controller. The rig is parent of character, so it cannot be affected by gravity. Therefore, I made a controller for movement and to be parent of rig. I want it to collide with some things, but not all. I want the character to collide with all. Sorry, I just realized I didn't mention this in question. However, I just want to know how to have the controller not interfere and collide with bullets.

Comment: Does the mask question answer this?